# Methods for controlling power outlets?

Tags: x-10, dmx512

I'm looking for ways to control power outlets (to turn them on/off) remotely and to schedule them.

This is not for my home, but for a larger exhibition hall.

So far I have found two different solutions, but I wan't to see if somebody maybe has a better solution.

1. Install a permanent [X10 based system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_%28industry_standard%29). All outlets needs to be changed.
2. Use something like a [ShowMaster](http://www.medialon.com/pr/showmaster_pro_mark_ii.aspx) (Pros: Can control projectors, dim show lights etc. Cons: Don't know if it can control power outlets, devices that don't support dmx, serial, ethernet comm.)

So far, the best solution maybe is a combination of these two. Some devices is ok to just cut the power to with e.g. a X10 module, and others are better to control with the ShowMaster e.g. projectors and show lights.

But is there other good solutions out there.

Comment: X10 has a limited number of devices and a limited range.

Comment: This sounds like a shopping question to me, not a design question.

Comment: Could you please give us more information such as the size a type of loads you are trying to switch, the distances between all the receiving devices and controls, whether you are trying to do this across phases and the safety and reliability needed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Digitalstrom](http://www.digitalstrom.com/) system would satify your needs:

- one seems to simply add a small screw terminal-like interface to the plug to be controlled
- and a central control device.

Also it appears that the system is using an open communication standard permitting the development of custom control software: [Digitalstrom Allianz](http://www.digitalstrom.org/)

[image]